# Math elementary textbooks

Tags: textbooks, mathematical-analysis

I’m a master student in Turkey. I’m researching math textbooks from different counties to compare them for my thesis. However, it is really difficult to find them. I need your suggestions. Or is there anyone who can share **elementary math book** with me? I’m so greatful if you can.
Thanks

Comment: This is likely to be extremely difficult unless you greatly narrow the scope (to two or three countries, and/or to two or three specific topics), since even just in the U.S. there are likely hundreds of books, and those will vary depending on whether it's a low performing school or high performing school, and additionally varying according to public school, private school, home-school text. Also, each of the 50 states have slightly different "guiding principles", which will affect the textbook coverage. Finally, what's in a book might have very little to do with what is actually taught!

Comment: What do you mean by "elementary math book"?  Do you mean mathematics textbooks for elementary (primary) school?

Comment: "even just in the U.S. there are likely hundreds of books" — this happens because the U.S. has no country-wide Ministry of Education and hence no MOE-approved textbooks, so everyone uses whatever they want. Gülümden, I suggest concentrating your research on the countries that have strict governmental control over education and rigorous textbook approval procedure, this would be most European countries, China, Japan, Russia.

Comment: Could you answer the question of Joel Reyes Noche ?understand that what you ask is ambiguous: addressing 8-10 years or 12-16 years scholars is not the same...

Answer (score 1):

Gunaydan.

Here is a lit review of US math elementary textbooks evolution:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/41103881?seq=1

Realistically your question is so broad that I think you need to learn more before you can even ask the right questions.  But maybe this will get you thinking.

For example, I would think about restricting your scope to two to three countries and one topic.  Maybe...decimals and Turkey, US, France.*  Questions to consider could be at what age is the material taught, how consistent is it within the country (I imagine France is more uniform than the US), and what methodology is emphasized (mnemonics, drill, etc.)  [An alternate approach might be more around business aspects: cost, selection, publishers.]

*Just an example.  Pick something that interests you.  I would also look at the approach in Turkey first, to orient yourself, prior to looking at other countries.

FWIW, I would also not lose sight of the similarities.  There's a scene in the movie Mean Girls where the heroine says math is her favorite class because it's the same in all languages.  This is not 100% true.  But it's MUCH more true than history or language.  (Based on my personal experience in Turkey.)  So in the midst of identifying differences, don't lose sight of similarities, either.

Comment: You begin this answer by indicating that the question itself is too broad.  Questions which are too broad are not really appropriate for the site.  Please don't answers questions which are not appropriate for the site---instead, consider leaving a comment (I am aware that you don't have enough reputation to comment right now, but obtaining sufficient reputation is not that difficult, though it does require maintaining a consistent account).

Comment: Even if the question is too broad, I think the answer by guest is helpful precisely because  it helps the OP to narrow it, if the OP wants to take it into consideration...